# cross domain call with jQuery jsonp to ASP.NET web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, cross-domain, jsonp

My problem is known issue and discussed [here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/adelkhalil/archive/2009/08/14/cross-domain-jsonp-with-jquery-call-step-by-step-guide.aspx) and [here](http://blog.jonathanroussel.com/2010/01/jsonp-your-aspnet-web-service-direction.html).
But even after reading and implementing the suggested solutions i am unable to make this work.

**The problem**: the web service returning xml insted of json:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"Now i am getting jsop string""2nd param"</string>
```

Now lets break the code into sections:

**THE REMOTE SERVER (IIS 7.0, .NET 4):**

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <modules>
                <add name="JsonHttpModule.JsonHttpModule" type="JsonHttpModule"/>
            </modules>
        </system.webServer>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="102400"/>
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet"/>
                <add name="HttpPost"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

the web service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using JsonHttpModule;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for JSONP_EndPoint
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string Sum(string x, string y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

}
```

the HttpModule class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ContentTypeHttpModule
/// </summary>
namespace JsonHttpModule
{
    public class JsonHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private const string JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
        public void Init(HttpApplication app)
        {
            app.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
            app.EndRequest += new EventHandler(OnEndRequest);
        }
        public void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpRequest request = app.Request;
            //Make sure we only apply to our Web Service
            if (request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower().Contains("MyService.asmx"))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.Context.Request.ContentType))
                {
                    app.Context.Request.ContentType = JSON_CONTENT_TYPE;
                }
                app.Context.Response.Write(app.Context.Request.Params["callback"] + "(");
            }
        }
        void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpRequest request = app.Request;
            if (request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower().Contains("MyService.asmx"))
            {
                app.Context.Response.Write(")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT SIDE (localhost):**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btn_test').click(function () {
            $.ajax({ url: "http://tonofweb.com/MyService.asmx/Sum",
                data: { x: JSON.stringify("Now i am getting jsop string"), y: JSON.stringify("2nd param") },
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (json) {
                    alert(json.d);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Hit error fn!");
                }
            });
    });
});
</script>
    <input id="btn_test" type="button" value="POST" />
```

so what am i doing wrong here?
you can test it yourselves it's a live web service.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: changing from jsonp to json not working due to cross domain issue
and converting to object still return xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems all the configuration and attributes are in place for the web service to return JSON but I did notice in your jQuery request, you are not specifying the content type of the data you are passing in. I have added it to the code below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://tonofweb.com/MyService.asmx/Sum",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: { x: JSON.stringify("1"), y: JSON.stringify("2") },
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (json) {
    alert(json.d);
  },
  error: function () {
    alert("Hit error fn!");
  }
});
```

Notice I added `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` to the request settings.

I have tested this code by browsing to http://tonofweb.com (which returns a 403 at the moment), including jQuery using the [jQuerify bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet/), and then running the code from your question first (**without** the contentType), and then the code I posted above (**with** the contentType).

Here are the responses from the Network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools:

**Without contentType**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"Now i am getting jsop string""2nd param"</string>
```

**With contentType**:

```
{"d":"12"}
```

So the second one at least results in JSON being returned from the server. So all else being equal, I'd say add the contentType.

See here for an explanation of the requirements to return JSON:

[ASMX and JSON – Common mistakes and misconceptions](http://encosia.com/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/)

> The HTTP request must declare a content-type of application/json. This
>   informs the ScriptService that it will receive its parameters as JSON
>   and that it should respond in kind.

Now you still have another problem, and that is that the request, upon completion, calls the error function. If you change `dataType: "jsonp"` to `dataType: "json"` it will call the success function. So something about your implementation of the callback wrapper is wrong, because jQuery can't handle the response as JSONP.

Now I'm not seeing the callback wrapped in the response either, for JSONP, the response should be something like:

```
jQuery17106476630216930062_1326752446188({"d":"12"})
```

I notice you are linking to [this post](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/adelkhalil/archive/2009/08/14/cross-domain-jsonp-with-jquery-call-step-by-step-guide.aspx) about how to do a JSONP response from a web service, but you are not following the advice: you don't use `Response.Filter`, instead you use `Response.Write`.

Comment: Yes, it is working, you stated: "The problem: the web service returning xml insted of json:". I just tested this code, and your web service responds with JSON if you only add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: i am still unable to get this to work even after i added contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" i am getting:

<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
"1""2"
</string

Comment: Follow my steps: open your website in a new Chrome browser tab, wait for 403 response, add jQuery using bookmarklet, copy and paste my request code into the console, hit enter, inspect the response using the Response tab. I have tried it just now (5 seconds ago) and the response is `{"d":"12"}`