# Error while passing multiple parameters on Jquery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, .net, json, web-services, jsonp

I am implementing .net webservice (asmx) using JSONP using [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43038/Accessing-Remote-ASP-NET-Web-Services-Using-JSONP).

When I call my webservice, with a single parameter it works. However, when I try to call with mulitple parameters i keep getting Network 500 error. I tried to use `"data: JSON.stringify({ jewellerId: filter, locale: 'en-US' }),"` as described in this stackoverflow question: [Pass Multiple Parameters to jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916309/pass-multiple-parameters-to-jquery-ajax-call). However it doesn't work.

Hers is my script:

```
function getData() 
{
    var key = "123";
    var code = "12458";
    jQuery.ajax({ url: http://service.com/test.asmx,
        data: JSON.stringify({ Key: key, Code: code }),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) 
        {
            alert(json.d);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Hit error fn!");
        }
    });
}
```

So, when i changed the webservice to take only one parameter, i changed the data to be like:
`data: {Key: JSON.stringify("123") }`  it worked.

Any suggestions how i can fix this?

Comment: Adding content type made it work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884928/cross-domain-call-with-jquery-jsonp-to-asp-net-web-service

Answer (score 2):

Don't stringify the data if you are sending it as GET (which is the case for jsonp requests)

```
function getData() {
    var key = "123";
    var code = "12458";
    jQuery.ajax({ url: http://service.com/test.asmx,
        data: { Key: key, Code: code },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) {
            alert(json.d);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Hit error fn!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the server you are requesting from can accept a request like this?