# Consuming WebService in Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, cross-domain

It should be very simple. I have read a lot of posts about consuming web service cross domain and the use of JSONP, but there is something I am missing.

If I call the following URL in the WebBrowser, I can get my result:
http://benfaniz.com.br/WebService.asmx/AAA_Buscar_Nome_Condominio?callback=?

To consume it using jQuery, I am using:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var surl = "http://benfaniz.com.br/webservice.asmx/AAA_Buscar_Nome_Condominio";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: surl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg.data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
                alert("error"); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voLovskc/8/)

But I keep getting error? What is the problem?

---

**UPDATE**

I can get the content of the URL using the following code (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function))

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


        var theUrl = "http://benfaniz.com.br/WebService.asmx/AAA_Buscar_Nome_Condominio?callback=?"            

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
            xmlhttp.send();    


    });
```

Please, look at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voLovskc/8/)

Comment: This is a .NET SOAP web service that returns XML.  The server is not configure to return JSONP and will fail if you try.  The workaround is to use a proxy server like Yahoo YQL to make the web service call and then return the data to you in json or xml format. See: [Yahoo YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/running-chapt.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do it. I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884928/cross-domain-call-with-jquery-jsonp-to-asp-net-web-service?answertab=active#tab-top) that gave me the directions.

The main problem is that I was getting a XML result instead of JSON. To change this, I had to add the line `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`.

The final code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var surl = "http://benfaniz.com.br/webservice.asmx/AAA_Buscar_Nome_Condominio";
    $.ajax({
        url: surl,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("ERRO");
        }
    }); 
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8smgc4xL/)

Comment: @Robert, it works. The problem I pasted the wrong fiddle link. Thanks.